# How to use NSPredicate with Multidimensional array (where the predicateFormat exists at valueForKeyPath)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an array where the 'id' on which i want to filter the array exists at `valueForKeyPath` 'objectId' of each of its dictionaries. How to compare the predicates in `ValueForKeyPath`.

Currently.. this predicate

```
NSPredicate * objIdPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId = %@",obj];
NSArray * oneOrder = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:objIdPredicate];
```

is considering key and values of the array elements, not the ones at their `ValueForKeyPath=@"objectId"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "self"in your code to get the array element's valueForKeyPath

NSPredicate *objIdPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.objectId = %@)",obj];

`

Comment: Didn't work. But i do think the solution is somewhere on the same lines

Comment: Try this ,just add  Parentheses

Comment: did you try this [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.objectId = %@)",obj];

Comment: you have dictionaries as the elements of your array right,this code works for me in a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks! .. it was at (self.order.objectId = %@). It was really helpful

Comment: In this case, you better use the method mentioned in this answer  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250575/objective-c-filter-array-of-nsdictionarys-and-nsdictionarys)